# How do I access data in a many-many table in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to EF, and I posted a question about what happened to my RecipeMeal table when I created my .edmx. 
Here is the diagram for both.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ18h.jpg

I learned that EF has built in support for many-many relationships and this is supposed to happen.

I'm confused though, how I access the data.

For example, (refer to the imgur link) if I want to get all recipes that have a meal name of "Lunch", how would I get that data?

EF 5.0 RC

Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with context.Recipes.Where(...)

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not sure how to write the where. I can do a where for Type, which is just a column, like this `db.Recipes.Where(x => x.Type == type)` but I don't see a way to write it for meal, which is a many to many relational table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like

```
from m in db.C_id_Meal
from r in m.Recipes
where m.Name == "lunch"
select new { m.Name, Recipe = r.Name, ... }
```

Comment: That would return all of the meal entries that match though, right? I'm trying to get all of the recipes that would match lunch in c_id_Meal. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Ack, sorry. I think maybe my where for type was confusing. That wasn't relevant to what I'm trying to get at now.
"Lunch" would be on C_id_Meal    

I also dont have a context.Meals. I only have context.db.C_id_Meal

Comment: The == "lunch" should be against the RecipeMeal table in db though, not the _id_TypeRecipe. This is where I'm getting confused, because I dont have a RecipeMeal table in EF.

Comment: But the RecipeMeal table has nothing to match `== lunch`, that's why Recipes and types have to get involved. Does my query not give the data you expected? Maybe you should include a sample output in your post to make it clear.

Comment: RecipeMeal has a RecipeId and a MealId. The MealId relates to the _id_Meal table, which has a Name column which would have lunch,dinner,snack etc.
Instead of lunch, the mealID is also perfectly fine with me, and is actually probably simpler. Here is SQL that does what I want, I'm just not sure how to do it in code with EF.
`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Recipes]
JOIN [dbo].[RecipeMeal] 
ON [dbo].[Recipes].RecipeId = [dbo].[RecipeMeal].RecipeId
WHERE [dbo].[RecipeMeal].MealId = 4`

Thanks again for the help and putting up with my unclear explanations. I hope this one is better.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I think I had two problems, one I didn't realize you could do two froms and a where without joining them both, which was making things a lot more complicated, and then second, i kept trying to do the where on r. instead of m. Such a simple concept was taking me such a long time to figure it out. Thank you again so much.